# Reverse triangle inequality for three summands

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb C$. Can we then say that $$|a+b+c|\geq\left||a||-|b|-|c|\right|$$

My guess is that since $|b+c|\leq |b|+|c|$ by the triangle inequality we can maybe pulg that into $$|a+b+c|=|a+(b+c)|\geq||a|-|b+c||\geq ||a|-|b|-|c||$$but I'm not sure if that holds. Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  false. Take $a=0, b=1, c=-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Does it change anything if we restrict to $a,b,c\in\mathbb C^\times$?

Comment: If you mean non-zero complex numbers, the answer is still NO. Take $a=1,b=100, c=-100$.

Comment: If you study the case when $b+c=0$ you will see why such an inequality does not hold.

Comment: I see, thanks again!